# Set NSLayoutConstraints for subview to parent view

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

In a UITableViewCell subclass I am adding a subview to the backgroundView:

```
-(void)method {
    [self.backgroundView addSubview:self.backView];
    [self setConstraintsForBackView];
}

-(UIView*)backView {
    if (!_backView) {
        _backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }
    return _backView;
}
```

I am trying to get the `backView` to size with the `backgroundView`. I figured using NSLayoutConstraints would be the best way, but the `backView` always appears with the original 44 point cell height, not the actual height I am setting for each cell. Here's the code for my NSLayoutConstraints

```
-(void)setConstraintsForBackView {
    [self.backView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:@{@"view": self.backView}]];
}
```

I am seeing the following error:

`'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x89662d0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x8e87c10]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x8e876c0 )> view:<UIView: 0x8e87c10; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x8e87c70>>'`

I have also tried `@"V:|-0-[view]-0-|"` without any luck.

Admittedly, I don't have a ton of experience with NSLayoutConstraints, but playing around with various visual formats doesn't yield any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the constraints to `self.backgroundView` not `self.backView`.

First: `self.backView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`

ie: `[self.backgroundView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:@{@"view": self.backView}]];`

Comment: Ah, thanks! Though I am seeing the following error: `(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x71df080 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x71de160.midY ==>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x71de3f0 V:[UIView:0x71de160]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x71de0d0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x71df200 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x71de0d0(77)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x71de370 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x71de160]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x71de0d0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x71de3f0 V:[UIView:0x71de160]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x71de0d0 )>`

Comment: Any idea? I wasn't able to paste in the whole error which describes it more in detail.

Comment: You also need `self.backView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`